# JQuery: Remove currently selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with JQuery's `draggable()` and `droppable()` functions and am having issues trying to remove the currently selected DIV.

Every time I drag an object onto my #canvas, a new DIV is appended to the #canvas and the `.newLetter` class is added to it.  My HTML looks something like below:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="canvas">
    <div id="trash"></div>
    <div class="newLetter"></div>
    <div class="newLetter"></div>
    <div class="newLetter"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Once on the canvas, I want the option of then dragging the object into a "trashcan" and being removed.  I ONLY want the currently selected DIV to be removed, but I can only get it to work if I remove all elements with the .newLetter class.  Otherwise, nothing is removed, or the wrong elements are removed (such as the trashcan itself or the entire canvas).

This is my current **JQuery:**

```
// Delete Letters
$("#trash").droppable({
    accept: '.newLetter',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(".newLetter").remove();
    }
});
```

I've tried doing all of the below but none of them are working:

```
$(this).remove();
$(".newLetter", this).remove();
$(this).sibling().remove();
$(this).parent().remove();
$(this).(".newLetter").remove();
$(this).closest().remove();
$(this).closest().sibling().remove();
```

I believe I have exhausted all possibilites.  Any ideas??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [drop event](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop), you can refer the dragged element reference using `ui.draggable`

```
$("#trash").droppable({
    accept: '.newLetter',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).remove();
        //or even ui.draggable.remove(); since ui.draggable is a jQuery object
    }
});
```

Comment: Genius!  I should have thought of that!  It worked perfectly.  Thanks.  Will there ever be a chance that more than one element will have the ui.draggable class at the same time?

Comment: @Keven `ui.draggable` is not a class name, it is a jQuery wrapper object.. so it will always represent the currently dragged element